# UnknownHostException with Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, apache, exception, httpclient

Hithere.

I am trying to perform a GET against a URL using DefaultHttpClient of Apache's HTTPClient library.

Here is my code:

```
    public String getHTML(String url) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(url);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("/");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

If I pass a URL such as "www.google.ie", I have no problems. However, if I use a URL with a relative path such as "www.google.ie/intl/en/ads/", it fails. I get an UnknownHostException thrown from the `httpclient.execute()` method above. It only happens with relative URLs and I'm not sure why. Has anyone any input as to why? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem. I had to pass the relative path into the HTTPGet. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host is `www.google.com` the rest is not a host but a path (or mapping) within the host. This should go to the `new HttpGet("_HERE_")`

So you will have:

```
new HttpGet("/intl/en/ads/");
```