# No internet on emulators with API 19 or lower

Tags: android

I'm having trouble getting emulators running Android versions prior to API 19 (including 19) to connect to the internet. Emulators running newer versions connect just fine. There's no connection at all, it's not that the app can't access the internet, nothing  in the device can. Mobile data is turned on and the 4G (or 3G) icon is showing.

I have tried different devices, but the problem seems to be the Android version itself. I also tried deleting and re-creating the device. Uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator, reinstalling Android studio, reinstalling SDK and tried forcing 3G to no avail too.

Sorry if I'm not being specific enough or providing any more info than this, but I'm not able to do much more and I haven't found anything online that helps me.

Is there any reason for this?

Thanks in advance

[Android Studio build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bod4g.png)
[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o8tw.png)

Comment: Have you checked if Airplane mode is on?

Comment: It's not on....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277064/internet-connection-not-working-if-my-app-runs-on-a-api-8-emulator

Comment: @HarshaW Yeah, I saw that, but it doesn't help. The OP says that the device can connect to the internet through the browser, but that the app he's testing can't. I should've mentioned that the device simply doesn't have an internet connection, I can't browse or sign in with Google or anything, even though the mobile data icon is showing.

Comment: Same issue with mine please update

Comment: @Sheychan The issue is solved, but I honestly don't remember what I did exactly. It wasn't anything fancy, try deleting the AVD and creating a new one or re-downloading the system image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I deleted emulator, than went to sdk manager and

- updated sdk platform fot 19 api
- updated and installed sdk tools as below:
  [installed sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOm3Y.png)